# calculating the probabilities in simple combinatorics problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

An engineering company has 4 openings: applicant pool consists of 6 database administrators and 8 network engineers.
All are equally qualified so the hiring will be done randomly.
The hiring committee consists of 4 women and 4 men.

1. If one person on the hiring committee is chosen at random to draw the names out of a hat, what is the probability that the person drawing the names is a woman?
   (**my answer** to this question is $4/(8) = 1/2$).
2. How many ways can the group who are to be hired be formed if there are no restrictions on composition?
   (**my attempt:** $C_{14}^4 = 14!/(4!\,10!))$
3. How many ways can 3 database administrators be chosen?
   (**my attempt:** $C_6^3$
4. How many ways can 1 network engineers be chosen?
   (**my attempt:** $C_8^1$
5. What is the probability that the random selection of the four persons to be hired will result in 3 database administrators and 1 network engineer?

Comment: Some of the questions are asking probabity but the others are not so you should check $3,4$

Answer (score 1):

You answers to $1-4$ are correct. For $5$, you have to do $\text{probability}={\text{number of ways} \over \text{total ways}}$. For the numerator, you multiply your answers to $3$ and $4$; the number of ways to have $3$ database engineers and one network engineer is $C_8^1\times C_6^3$. The denominator is your answer to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

1. (my answer to this question is 4/(8) = 1/2).
2. (my attempt: $C_{14}^4 = 14!/(4!10!))$
3. (my attempt: $C_6^3$
4. (my attempt: $C_8^1$
5. **Corrected**  $(C_6^3 \times C_8^1)/C_{14}^4$

Comment: Welcome to MSM! Note that you can put this info into your original question.